# Qt/QWebSocket cant connect to Socket IO server

Tags: c++, qt, websocket, socket.io

I am trying to connect my C++ Qt based client app to websocket server made with NodeJS/Socket io.

Here is my code:

MyApp.h:

```
QWebSocket* socket;
```

MyApp.cpp:

```
void MyApp::on_connectButton_clicked()
{
    socket = new QWebSocket();
std::cout << "BUTTON CLICKED" << std::endl;

QUrl url("https://socket.address.test:3000");
socket->open(url);

QObject::connect(socket, &QWebSocket::connected, [&]() {
    qDebug() << "Connected to the server!";
});

QObject::connect(socket, &QWebSocket::disconnected, [&]() {
    qDebug() << "Disconnected from the server!";
});

QObject::connect(socket, &QWebSocket::textMessageReceived, [](const QString &message) {
    qDebug() << "Received message:" << message;
});

// Sending a message to the server
QString message = "Hello, Server!";
socket->sendTextMessage(message);
}
```

When I click the button to connect I see the message "BUTTON CLICKED" but actual connection really never happens, nor any error is shown. Note that when I use Postman to test my websocket server all seems to work with it. So the server is fine and running.

It just seems that I can't connect to it via my C++ Qt client. Any idea where is the issue and how can I fix it ?

Comment: Try connecting to the error signal